# Dynamic JPA Querys : "property not found"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm pretty new in JPA/Hibernate and spring boot, and I'd like to do dynamic querys depeding on the received params. I was following this approach https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query , but I'm getting an error :

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application startup failedCaused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getReglas2doNivelFiltradas found for type Reglas2doNivel!
```

This how I implemented :

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface Reglas2doNivelRepository extends JpaRepository<Reglas2doNivel, Long>, Reglas2doNivelRepositoryCustom {

    @Modifying
    @Query("Update Reglas1erNivel r set r.activo='N' where r.id_regla = ?1")
    void desactivarRegla2doNivel(Long iRegla);

    @Query("Select r from Reglas2doNivel r where r.sociedad.id_sociedad = ?1")
    List<Reglas2doNivel> getReglas2doNivelBySociedad(int companyID);

}
```

Custom repository interface:

```
public interface Reglas2doNivelRepositoryCustom {

    List<Reglas2doNivel> getReglas2doNivelFiltradas(int company, List<Integer> areasId,  int ordenDesde, int ordenHasta, String nemoTecnico);
}
```

Custom Repository implemetation:

```
public class Reglas2doNivelRepositoryCustomImpl implements Reglas2doNivelRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Reglas2doNivel> getReglas2doNivelFiltradas(int company, List<Integer> areasId, int ordenDesde,
            int ordenHasta, String nemoTecnico) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Service :

```
@Override
public List<Reglas2doNivel> getReglas2doNivelBySociedad(int companyID) {
            
    return reglas2doNivelRepository.getReglas2doNivelBySociedad(companyID);
}
```

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: That you aren't following the proper conventions. The custom implementation isn't detected and thus it will try to make a query from the method (which fails). Make sure the name is exactly as it should be name of interface + `Impl` and that both files are in the same package and not a different one!.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I dont understand your point. The names are: Reglas2doNivelRepositoryCustomImpl  and Reglas2doNivelRepositoryCustom , so is the same +Impl. What is the wrong name?

Comment: and they must be in the same package as well.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same package, the threee repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation to the `Reglas2doNivelRepositoryCustom` interface and `@Repository` to the `Reglas2doNivelRepositoryCustomImpl`